# Why there is no phase relationship between the $y$ and $z$ components of electric fields in an unpolarised light

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]The book says:

> if light is travelling along $x$ axis, there is no phase relationship between the $y$ and $z$ components of the electric fields in an unpolarised light, 
>   my concern is will there be any phase relation between the two in a polarised light, when the $y$ and $z$ components are just the components of the same wave.[image]

How there will be no phase relationship, I believe it should be 0, if there is no relationship it should be between any two waves not with the components of the same wave.

Answer (score 2):

> my concern is will there be any phase relation between the two in a polarised light,

For example, if the polarization is linear, then the y and z components are in phase (or exactly 180 degrees out of phase). Or possibly one of the components is 0. Or, if the polarization is circular, then there is a 90 degree phase difference between the y and z components.

> when the y and z components are just the components of the same wave,how there will be no phase relationship,I believe it should be 0,

If you have 0 phase difference between the y and z components of $\vec{E}$, then you have linearly polarized light with $\vec{E}$ in the direction at 45 degrees between $\hat{y}$ and $\hat{z}$.

> if there is no relationship it should be between any two waves not with the components of the same wave.

In order to have unpolarized light, you do need the y and z components to be uncorrelated. This does imply that they are produced by statistically independent processes, and so it would be fair to say they're separate waves. It also generally implies that the process producing the light is incoherent. If it were producing a single frequency, the same for both the x and y components of $\vec{E}$, then there would be *some* phase relationship between them, even if it were not well controlled. So that means, not only is the y-polarized light a separate wave from the z-polarized light, but also the y-polarized light at $t=0$ is a separate wave from the y-polarized light at $t=\epsilon$, for fairly small values of $\epsilon$.

Comment: I am adding the full version of the book so that the question may become simpler and clear,

Comment: "polarisation by scattering". The light from a clear blue portion of the sky shows a rise and fall of intensity when viewed through a polaroid which is rotated,This is nothing but sunlight,which has changed its direction (having been scattered) on encountering the molecules of the earth's atmosphere.

Comment: The dots stand for polarisation perpendicular to the plane of the paper,the double arrows show polarisation in the plane of the paper(there is no phase relation between these two in unpolarised light).Under the influence of the electric field of the incident wave the electrons in the molecules acquire components of motion in both these directions.

Comment: If an observer is drawn looking at 90 degrees to the direction of the sun,clearly,charges accelerating parallel to the double arrows do not radiate energy towards this observer since their acceleration has no transverse component.The radiation scattered by the molecule is therefore represented by dots.It is polarised perpendicular to the planed of the paper,This explains the polarisation of scattered light from the sky.

Comment: @sachin, that is telling you that when you observe light scattered in the atmosphere, it **is** polarized. The question you asked is about light that **isn't** polarized. If you want to ask about the atmospheric scatter situation, you should post a new question. Include all the relevant material needed to understand the question in your question post.

Comment: PhotonI apologise for the same but the dots and arrows come in any kind of polarisation situation like polarisation by refleciton,my concern was if we draw sinusoidal waves along the y and z axis,then both reach the peak at the same time meaning both in phase,if possible pl revisit the explanation within the brackets in the second sentence what I am reposting.

Comment: (there is no phase relation between these two in unpolarised light) in "The dots stand for polarisation perpendicular to the plane of the paper,the double arrows show polarisation in the plane of the paper(there is no phase relation between these two in unpolarised light).Under the influence of the electric field of the incident wave the electrons in the molecules acquire components of motion in both these directions."

Comment: What dots and arrows? I can't read your mind. You could edit your question to include the diagram you're asking about. But since somebody already answered the question you did ask, it's a bit rude to move the goalposts. To ask a new question, just post a new question, and **include all the information needed to understand the question**.

Comment: To explain the parenthetical, "there is no phase relation between these in unpolarized light", read the first paragraph of my answer. To restate what I already said: If there was a fixed phase relationship between the two polarizations you'd have linear, circular, or elliptically polarized light, so it wouldn't be unpolarized.

Comment: I have answered your question as best I can in my first paragraph. If there is a fixed phase relationship between the y and z components, then you have polarized light. Therefore you don't have unpolarized light.